# How to graph root growth rate against shoot growth rate in one graph in R on two different y axes

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph

I am having trouble making a line graph, with two treatments (three replications of each treatment), of root growth over time vs aboveground lateral shoot growth. I want the lateral shoot growth y axis to be cm per day and the root growth axis to be mm per day.

So I created this but for some reason, this is not working - I got the error message
"Error in layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomLine,  :
object 'Treatment' not found" even though I plugged in the data, read in the Treatment and replicate.

```
ggplot(Growth_rateSeptC18, aes(x = Date) +
       geom_line (aes (y = rootlength_root), color = Treatment, group = Treatment) +
         geom_line(aes (y = AvgLoverall), color = Treatment, group = Treatment) +
         sec_axis(~.*coeff, name="Lateral growth - cm/day") +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.2), size = 1) +
  labs(x="Date", y = "root growth - mm/day") +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank (), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        panel.background = element_blank())
)
```

Would anybody be able to help? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide some data. For example with `dput()`.

Comment: It looks like `color = Treatment ... etc.` is outside the `aes()` call, so ggplot interprets it differently. Instead of looking for a variable called `Treatment` it is looking for an object in your environment called `Treatment`. The color and group mappings belong inside the `aes()` along with your `y` mapping.